# Android Studio Button OnClick Causing Failure?

Tags: android

I'm working on an application for android in Android Studio and I'm attempting to make an on-click listener like so:

```
    Button menu_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
    menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     }
    });
```

However, when I start genymotion it tells me that the app has stopped working. If I remove this code:

```
    menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     }
    });
```

The application runs fine. I'm very confused and was hoping maybe someone could point something out I'm not understanding.

Here's the full code of the main activity I'm working on, and I should note that the button is inside a ViewPager.

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private ViewPager m_BackgroundViewPager;
private ViewPager m_PanelViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m_BackgroundViewPager = (ViewPager)(findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager));
    m_PanelViewPager = (ViewPager)(findViewById(R.id.bottomViewPager));

    m_BackgroundViewPager.setAdapter
            (new BackgroundPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
    m_PanelViewPager.setAdapter
            (new PanelPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));

    Button menu_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
    menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     }
    });
   }
  }
```

LogCat Results:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at eqlogic.annswingsandthings.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#998822">
<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post logs of the exception

Comment: Post the exception occuring

Comment: try my answer @Eidenai

Comment: @DivyaNagrath - I added the logcat. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: It's like, for some reason, the setting of the button is not working.

Comment: is the id which u r using "menu_button" correct? Ps- post ur xml too

Comment: @DivyaNagrath - Turns out I'm just retarded and need to figure out how to get the ID from another xml layout because the button exists in the framelayout used for one of the viewpager fragments. Oh and I added the XML.

Comment: menu_button is null because it is not part of activity_main.xml

When you call findViewById inside an Activity, it is going to look for a View inside your Activity's layout.

Comment: @DivyaNagrath - Thanks for entertaining my failures as an android developer. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable for your `Button` as follows :

```
Button menu_button;
```

Then in your `onCreate()` you add this line :

```
menu_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
```

And now whenever you want to make a `setOnClickListener()` you can do it like you were doing :

```
menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //Your click stuff
    }
});
```

### EDIT

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Make sure that in your `activity_main.xml` your `button` has this :

```
android:id="@+id/menu_button"
```

Comment: Unfortunately creating a global variable still throws the same error. I posted the log in the original post.

Comment: make sure that in your `activity_main` you have menu_button.... as the ID for your button

Comment: Turns out I'm just retarded. I added the XML but I did not realize the get view by ID was only within the current layout. So I need to figure out how to get that button from another layout form. Thanks for your help. I'm up voting, for dealing with stupidity. Even though I can apparently not do upvote due to my rep.

Comment: You can mark my answer as acorrect :), you can not, you have to put this button on your `activity_main`

Comment: Could I still provide the functionality needed to keep the button moving with the viewpager on-swipe? That's my concern of moving it to the main layout.

Comment: @Eidenai Yep, you could do that

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the button is inside the view pager.

So in order to display the button either remove it out of the view pager or add it to the xml of the fragment which forms part of the view pager and inflate it in that fragment.

Comment: Could you elaborate for me? Maybe an example of the code? I'm already inflating both view pagers and if I remove it from the view pager then it will not move when sliding.